# How to keep only duplicate values from another list?

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, google-sheets-formula

Basically I am trying to keep only duplicate values that appear in another list, so that I know which products are fast moving.

For example, I have the following original list:

```
Confectionery
Haribo
Twix
Maoam
Refreshers
Bounty
Twix
Malteasers
Snickers
Dairymilk
Wispa
Galaxy
Twirl
Fruit-tella
```

Then I have another list:

```
Fruit-tella
7Up
Coca-Cola
Sprite
Haribo
Ribena
Twix
Bounty
Snickers
Boost
Red Bull
Mountain Dew
```

Effectively, I only want to keep values that appear in both lists, so in my case only the following should be taken:

```
Fruit-tella
Haribo
Twix
Bounty
Snickers
```

How would I go about doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(A:A, COUNTIF(B:B, A:A))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, it works! Could you please explain a bit on how the `FILTER` function works and how the `COUNTIF` bit works?

Comment: @RusMarcoderin formula says: we filter A column only if countif is true, eg. if column B contains whats in column A

Comment: thanks for explaining i accepted your answer just now